# What time of day was the afternoon korban mincha offered in the beit hamikdash, according to hazal?

Tags: zemanim, korban, mishna

At what halachic hour did chazal think the korban mincha was actually offered, assuming ideal circumstances? I.e. when they say "from the time of the mincha and onwards" (e.g. [Rosh Hashana 4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.4.4)) what hours do they have in mind exactly? Does this just mean from the beginning of mincha ketana onwards or something else?

Comment: Which Korban Mincha? Do you mean the Tamid shel Bein HaArbayim?

Comment: Did you see Pesachim 5:1

Comment: That's my question, too! When they are talking specifically about something that happened in the Beit HaMikdash (as in mRH 4:4) and they say: הִתְקִינוּ שֶׁלֹּא יְהוּ מְקַבְּלִין אֶלָּא עַד הַמִּנְחָה. וְאִם בָּאוּ עֵדִים מִן הַמִּנְחָה וּלְמַעְלָה, נוֹהֲגִין אוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם קֹדֶשׁ וּלְמָחָר קֹדֶשׁ what do they mean by "the mincha?" The mincha with the afternoon tamid we use to set our davening times? So basically they're talking about mincha ketana? (It's a simple low-level question. I just wanted to make sure I understood what they meant by that ambiguous phrase. Thank you for your patience!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is called the time of mincha is actually the time of the afternoon tamid (for explanations of the name, see [Tosafot Pesachim 107a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.107a.13.1)). The afternoon tamid was generally slaughtered at eight and a half hours into the day and sacrificed at nine and a half hours into the day ([Pesachim 5:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Pesachim.5.1); see there for when it was slaughtered earlier on Erev Pesach). Since [Rosh Hashshana 4:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.4.4) is due to the levites' song, it makes sense that the intention here is while the tamid is sacrificed, which is when the levites sang (during the [pouring of wine on it](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Vessels_of_the_Sanctuary_and_Those_who_Serve_Therein.3.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Comment: The witnesses of the new moon would have to come before the slaughtering of the tamid shel bein haarbaim, I would think, because the musaf offering has to be brought before the tamid (Yuma 33a). This would make the deadline eight and a half hours, and the song of the leviim at nine and a half, as well as the actual mincha (as in Yuma ibid.). There might be room to argue if the musaf could still be brought, bidiavad, after the tamid.

Comment: @Mordechai That's Tosafot's question ([RH 30b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.30b.6?lang=he&with=Tosafot&lang2=he)) - they answer, as you suggest, that they would have been able to offer the musaf after the tamid