# Why is הַמִּנְחָ֗ה in 1kings 18:36 translated as "Evening" sacrifice?

Tags: translation, korban, melachim-kings-book-of

Is this just an assumption or does it have to do with the prefix?

interlinear:
https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_kings/18-36.htm
parallel:
https://biblehub.com/1_kings/18-36.htm

Comment: To have a common denominator, try to avoid using Christian translations on MY. In this particular case it's not an issue, but it would make life easier for other users. https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a18.htm#36

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104665/what-time-of-day-was-the-afternoon-korban-mincha-offered-in-the-beit-hamikdash

Comment: @Tesvov Does the definition have anything to do with prefixes or suffixes?

Comment: Do you know if there is a prefix or suffix? Why do you think the translation depends on an affix?

Comment: I just wonder how 'sacrifice' becomes 'evening sacrifice' because of the הַ prefix.

Comment: It doesn't -- it becomes "the meal offering". The next step would be to decide what "evening" means and see how it connects to the time associated with the meal offering.

Comment: I'm speaking of the translated sentence. How in this translation does evening come into play? It could be evening it could be morning it could be midday, why was the word evening chosen?

Comment: "And it came to pass at the offering of the sacrifice Elijah the prophet came near and said."   I don't see how this says anything about evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> וַיְהִי בַּעֲלוֹת הַמִּנְחָה וַיִּגַּשׁ אֵלִיָּהוּ הַנָּבִיא וַיֹּאמַר יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם יִצְחָק וְיִשְׂרָאֵל הַיּוֹם יִוָּדַע כִּי־אַתָּה אֱלֹהִים בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל וַאֲנִי עַבְדֶּךָ וּבִדְבָרְךָ עָשִׂיתִי אֵת כָּל־הַדְּבָרִים הָאֵלֶּה׃
> When it was time to present the meal-offering, the prophet Elijah came forward and said, “O LORD, God of Abraham, Isaac, and Israel! Let it be known today that You are God in Israel and that I am Your servant, and that I have done all these things at Your bidding." [I_Kings.18.36](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.18.36?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) *JPS translation*

Keep in mind that a translation is also an interpretation! This is what [Metzudas David](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.18.36?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_I_Kings.18.36.1&lang2=bi) says in place: "בעת העלאת מנחת הערב, הוא התמיד של בין הערבים" - it was the obligatory evening offering.

There are two daily "obligatory" meal offerings/sacrifices - one at the dawn and one in the evening. In this case, the translation hints that it was the evening meal-offering.

I'm not going to argue with Metzudas David, but it seems that it was in the evening not because it was the "obligatory" sacrifice, but because they actually spent the whole day trying to summon their gods.

Note, that not all translations read "evening", because it is not a literal translation but an interpretation.:
[image]

Comment: It's odd that he assumes that since Solomons 1000 sacrifices must have been all throughout the day. Wasn't this sacrifice done away from the temple also?

Comment: As I put in my answer, normally this would be forbidden but Elijah says he did it at the explicit command of Hashem @PabbleGoobs

Comment: There's a third daily obligatory meal offering: the chavitin. Because it is unique and definite, it may be the simplest pshat reading.

Comment: @DoubleAA Two offerings: the havitin was brought half in the morning, half in the evening.

Comment: @magicker72 Ah yes. I still think that is the pshat as opposed to nesachim of the tamid.

Answer (score 1):

It had to be the evening sacrifice because [verse 18:29](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15902/showrashi/true#v29) shows that the false prophets had been trying all day

> And as the afternoon passed and they feined to prophesy until the time
> of the sacrifice of the [evening] offering, and there was no voice and
> no answer and no one was listening.

Thus, the time of the sacrifice had to be in the evening.

Also note this would normally be forbidden and that Elijah said

> "Lord, the God of Abraham, Isaac and Israel, today let it be known
> that You are God in Israel and that I am Your servant, and at Your
> word have I done all these things.

because, as Rashi explains,

> **and at Your word I have done:** that I sacrificed on a high place at the time of
> the prohibition of high places.